# Matplotlib: Plot without line, but advanced colors

Tags: python, matplotlib

I was wondering if (and if so how) it is possible to make a plot with only markers (so without connecting lines between), like:

```
 plt.plot(x, y, 'or')
```

but instead of using r using a color from the list of colors (https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/gallery/color/named_colors.html), like:

```
plt.plot(x, y, 'ogrey')
```

which however does not work, I also tried

```
plt.plot(x, y, marker='o', color = 'grey')
```

but then again the points get connected. So I was wondering, if there is a possibility (i.e. kind of an empty linestyle) to solve that, but I wasn't able to find anything.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Try `plt.scatter`?

Comment: Oh yes, that was easy. Thank you very much